# How to show bootstrap v4 modal box inside a container div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Working with the bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha is pretty awesome, here what I am looking for: I need to put modal box inside the container div, not on whole screen. [image]

I tried with changing some builtin CSS classes and yeah some JavaScript :) like:

> z-index: 1051;

Changing in right navBar but not satisfy with that is there, any simple solution?

Comment: Set `position` of model using css

Comment: If you want a modal box inside a static div maybe you should use panel instead. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels

Comment: yeah i try panels, not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: i mean i tried but didn't work

Comment: panels don't exist in bootstrap 4.  Cards maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a variable `var mod` and load modal in it;

   ```
   var mod = $('.modal');
   ```
2. Create a div `<div class="insidemodal"></div>` inside container where you want to show the modal
3. Use [Bootstrap 4 modal event listener](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/), preferable `show.bs.modal` and put `var mod = $('.modal');` inside it and load the modal in `insidemodal` selector when modal about to show.

   ```
   $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
       var mod = $('.modal'); //Create variable and load modal in it
       $('.insidemodal').html(mod); //Load modal to `insidemodal` Selector
   });
   ```
4. Make following Changes in `Modal` CSS

   ```
   .modal-backdrop {
       display:none //<---Kill the modal backdrop
   }
   .modal-backdrop.in {
       opacity: 0;
   }
   .modal {
       z-index: inherit !important; //<--overwrite modal default z-index: 1050
       position: relative; //<change position from absoulte
   }
   ```

So Final Code will be

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        var mod = $('.modal'); 
        $('.insidemodal').html(mod);
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.title {
    background: green;
    color:#fff;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid;
}
.menu {
    background: blue;
    color:#fff;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid;
}
.insidemodal {
    background: red;
    border:1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
}
.modal-backdrop {
    display:none
}
.modal-backdrop.in {
    opacity: 0;
}
.modal {
    z-index: inherit !important;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="title">This Is Title</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="menu">Left Menu
                <br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modal</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="insidemodal"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
 <span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">...</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bvy8erc3/)

**SideNote** If you have multiple modals, Above CSS changes in Modal CSS can cause other modals to not behave properly, so use custom selector instead making changes in default modal selector.